# Printing a pdf of more than 5000 pages takes longtime using Prawn pdf gem

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, prawn

I am using prawn pdf gem to print pdf.

I am formatting the data in to tables and then printing it to the pdf. I have around 5000 pages (about 50000 entries) to print and it takes forever. For small number of pages its quick ... Is there any way I can improve the speed of printing.

Also, printing without the data in table format was quick. please help me out with this.

code for this :

```
format.pdf {

    pdf = Prawn::Document.new(:margin => [20,20,20,20])
    pdf.font "Helvetica"
    pdf.font_size 12

    @test_points_all = Hash.new
    dataset_id = Dataset.where(collection_success: true).order('created_at DESC').first

    if(inode.leaf?)
        meta=MetricInstance.where(dataset_id: dataset_id, file_or_folder_id: inode.id).includes(:test_points,:file_or_folder,:dataset).first
        @test_points_all[inode.name] =  meta.test_points                 
    else
        nodes2 = []
        nodes2 = inode.leaves

        if(!nodes2.nil?)
            nodes2.each do |node|
                meta=MetricInstance.where(dataset_id: dataset_id, file_or_folder_id: node.id).includes(:test_points,:file_or_folder,:dataset).first
                @test_pointa = meta.test_points
                if(!@test_pointa.nil?)
                    @test_points_all[node.name] = @test_pointa
                end
            end    
        end
    end

    @test_points_all.each do |key, points|
        table_data = [["<b> #{key} </b>", "<b>433<b>","xyz","xyzs"]]
        points.each do |test|
            td=TestDescription.find(:first, :conditions=>["test_point_id=?", test.id])

            if (!td.nil?)
               table_data << ["#{test.name}","#{td.header_info}","#{td.comment_info}","#{td.line_number}"]
            end

            pdf.move_down(5)
            pdf.table(table_data, :width => 500, :cell_style => { :inline_format => true ,:border_width => 0}, :row_colors => ["FFFFFF", "DDDDDD"]) 

            pdf.text ""

            pdf.stroke do
                pdf.horizontal_line(0, 570)
            end

            pdf.move_down(5)
        end
    end


    pdf.number_pages("<page> of <total>", {
                    :start_count_at => 1,
                    :page_filter => lambda{ |pg| pg > 0 },
                    :at => [pdf.bounds.right - 50, 0],
                    :align => :right,
                    :size => 9
                  })

    pdf.render_file File.join(Rails.root, "app/reports", "x.pdf")
    filename = File.join(Rails.root, "app/reports", "x.pdf")
    send_file filename, :filename => "x.pdf", :type => "application/pdf",:disposition => "inline"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

The first of those two lines is pointless, take it out!

```
nodes2 = []
nodes2 = inode.leaves
```

Based on your information, i understand that the following query to the database seems to be performed around 50000 times ... Depending on the volume and content of your table, it might be very reasonable to perform one single query (fetching the whole table) at the start of your whole script, and to keep this data in memory to perform any following operations on it in pure Ruby, without talking to the database. Then again, if the table you are working with is insanely huge, it might also totally clog up your memory and be not a good idea at all. It really depends ... so figure it out!

```
TestDescription.find(:first, :conditions=>["test_point_id=?", test.id])
```

Also, if, as you say, printing without tables was very quick, you might be able to achieve a major speedup by reimplementing that minor part of table functionality you are actually using yourself, with only low level functions from prawn. Why? Prawn's table function is surely made to fulfill as many usecases as possible, and therefore includes a lot of overhead (at least form the perspective of someone who needs only barebones functionality - For everyone else this "overhead" is gold!). And therefore you can just implement that little part of tables you need yourself, and that might just give you a major performance boost. Give it a shot!

Comment: my app is handling a lot of data and seeing the performance the app ... i dont think saving all the entries in the memory would be a feasible option ..... but as you said running the database query 50k times is not good .... do you see any other alternative to it .... like fetching the records block by block or something like that ?

Comment: If you find a sensible way to group and segment the data from the db into bigger blocks, that is an option as well! I'd like to just emphasize that my last suggestion is probably the most important for you (as you stated it were the tables that introduced the real speed drop, and not the code you already had before). Therefore concentrate on getting this right, and leverage the other options afterwards, if you still need to. :)

Comment: I am currently working on a program making use of prawn-table and finding a similar issue when the tables are introduced. Something within that gem slows down performance dramatically, which I noticed using ruby-prof. Still figuring out possible workarounds...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of ActiveRecord, I'd suggest using pluck in your inner loop. Instead of this:

```
td=TestDescription.find(:first, :conditions=>["test_point_id=?", test.id])
if (!td.nil?)
    table_data << ["#{test.name}","#{td.header_info}","#{td.comment_info}","#{td.line_number}"]
 end
```

Try this instead:

```
td = TestDescription.where(test_point_id: test.id)
  .pluck(:name, :header_info, :comment_info, :line_number).first
table_data << td unless td.blank?
```

Instead of instantiating an ActiveRecord object for each TestDescription, you'll just get back an array of field values that you should be able to append directly to table_data, which is really all you need here. This means less memory usage, and less time spent in GC.

It might also be worth trying to use pluck to retrieve all the entries at once, in which case you'd have an array of arrays to loop over. This would take more memory than fetching one at a time, but a lot less than an array of AR objects, and you'd save doing separate db queries.